# Using net.exe within VB.net WinForms app to remove a network drive

Tags: .net, vb.net, mapped-drive

I am attempting to add a button to my program that when clicked, will take an IP address of a NAS from a text box and plug it into "net use \\[IP]\IPC$ /delete". my code looks like this:

```
    Dim netdel As New ProcessStartInfo()
    netdel.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\net.exe"
    netdel.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32"
    netdel.Arguments = "use \\" + Convert.ToString(NAS_IP.Text) + "\IPC$ /delete"
    Process.Start(netdel)
```

I am not getting any errors or exceptions, but the code simply doesn't work. If I open CMD and type "net use" I still see the IP of the NAS mapped. I have attempted to do this several ways and they all seem to fail. I even had my program write a .bat script on the fly and then execute it, but even that doesn't work. (It is worth nothing that the actual bat script does work when you click on it manually, but launching it from within the code with process.start(netdel.bat) is unsuccessful). Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My crystal ball says that you run your Winforms program with UAC elevation.  So it works just fine, but you just can't see that it did when you double-check from a non-elevated command prompt.

Comment: So the user context when running net use will show different results? You are correct about my app running as admin. would having it run with highest rights for the current user fix this issue? or do I have to force the bat script to run as admin as well?